# A function which return employees with the highest employee count in the department in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, filter, foreach

I am a beginner in programming and solving exercises for logic building.

I have an array of employees.
Like This One (Actual array has more data, this is just an example):

```js
let arr = [
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    department: {
      name: 'admin',
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'Chris',
    department: {
      name: 'account',
    },
  },
];
```

Now I want to return Employees with the Highest count in the Department

I have counted number of employees per department

```js
const counts = {};
employees.forEach( (employee)=>{
  counts[employee.department.name] = (counts[employee.department.name] || 0) + 1;
});


console.log(counts) // { Accounts: 1, admin: 1 }
```

But I want to return Employees with highest count of with Department and instead of number of employees I want to return each employee object.

This is the expected output:

```js
{
  name: 'Employee1'
  {
    department:'Admin'
  }
},
{
    name: 'Employee2'
  {
    department:'Admin'
  }
},
{
    name: 'Employee3'
  {
    department:'Admin'
  }
}
```

I just need a guide for what to do next.

Thanks

Comment: so push to an array instead of count. The biggest number would be the longest array

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected returned object?

Comment: @maxpsz I have updated my question and now there is expected output too, thanks for your time.

Comment: as you already have the department count, you can easily determine the department with highest count, now you can simply filter out the employees who are working in that department using the filter() : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of number, I store employees by their department in an object (hashmap).
Then to extract the largest one, I've created a function that returns an object having the department and list of employees.

Feel free to run the code below and see the results.

```
let employees = [
  {
    name: "Tom",
    department: {
      name: "admin"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Chris",
    department: {
      name: "account"
    }
  }
];

const counts = {};
employees.forEach((employee) => {
  counts[employee.department.name] = (
    counts[employee.department.name] || []
  ).concat(employee.name);
});

console.log(counts); // {admin: ['Tom'], account: ['Chris']}


function getLargest(map) {
  let max = 0;
  let biggestDepartment = null;
  Object.entries(map).forEach(([department, arr]) => {
    if (max < arr.length) {
      max = arr.length;
      biggestDepartment = department;
    }
  });

  return {
    name: biggestDepartment,
    employees: map[biggestDepartment]
  }
}

console.log(getLargest(counts))
```

Answer (score 0):

So my solution is that you first group the employees w.r.t. department and then you can get the department with the highest employee count using the ***.length*** property.

```
const getGroupDepartments = (employees) => {
  const groupedDepartments = {};
  employees?.forEach((employee) => {
    groupedDepartments[employee.department.name] = groupedDepartments[employee.department.name] ? 
      [...groupedDepartments[employee.department.name], employee] : [employee]
  });
  return groupedDepartments
}

const getLargestDepartment = (employees) => {
  const departments = getGroupDepartments(employees)

  let largestDepartment;
  for (const department in departments) {
    if(largestDepartment?.length < departments[department].length || !largestDepartment){
      largestDepartment = departments[department]
    }  
  }
  return largestDepartment
}
```